# Volume fadeOut using AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters

Tags: objective-c, media-player, avplayer, fadeout, avplayeritem

I want to fadeout the sound track when the user clicks on the stop button for example, I use this code for fading out the sound

```
-(void)soundFadeOut{

AVPlayerItem *myAVPlayerItem = mainPlayer.currentItem;
AVAsset *myAVAsset = myAVPlayerItem.asset;
NSArray *audioTracks = [myAVAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {

        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];
        [audioInputParams setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.0 toEndVolume:0 timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(0, 1), CMTimeMake( 5, 1))];
        [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];

}
AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];
[myAVPlayerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];}
```

but when I click on the button the sound volume goes to Zero at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know my fault now, it was in the first CMTime parameter in the CMTimeRange

```
        CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(0, 1), CMTimeMake( 5, 1);
```

I found that the first `CMTimeMake` points to the second that will start fading out in my case the current second, and the other `CMTimeMake` is for the duration of fading out